# Finding correlation coefficient from 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I am working on a project which has many functions when given a couple lists of data. I've already seperated the lists and I have defined some functions which I know for certain work correctly, that being a mean function and standard deviation function. My issue is when testing my lists I get a correct mean, correct standard deviation, but incorrect correlation coefficient. Could my math be off here? I need to find the correlation coefficient with only Python's standard library.

**MY CODE:**

```
def correlCo(someList1, someList2):

    # First establish the means and standard deviations for both lists.
    xMean = mean(someList1)
    yMean = mean(someList2)
    xStandDev = standDev(someList1)
    yStandDev = standDev(someList2)
    zList1 = []
    zList2 = []

    # Create 2 new lists taking (a[i]-a's Mean)/standard deviation of a
    for x in someList1:
        z1 = ((float(x)-xMean)/xStandDev)
        zList1.append(z1)

    for y in someList2:
        z2 = ((float(y)-yMean)/yStandDev)
        zList2.append(z2)

    # Mapping out the lists to be float values instead of string     
    zList1 = list(map(float,zList1))
    zList2 = list(map(float,zList2))
    # Multiplying each value from the lists
    zFinal = [a*b for a,b in zip(zList1,zList2)]
    totalZ = 0
    # Taking the sum of all the products
    for a in zFinal:
        totalZ += a
    # Finally calculating correlation coefficient
    r = (1/(len(someList1) - 1)) * totalZ

    return r
```

**SAMPLE RUN:**

I have a list of [1,2,3,4,4,8] and [3,3,4,5,8,9]

I expect the correct answer of r = 0.8848, but get r = .203727

**EDIT: To include the mean and standard deviation functions I have made.**

```
def mean(someList):
    total = 0
    for a in someList:
        total += float(a)
    mean = total/len(someList)
    return mean

def standDev(someList):
    newList = []
    sdTotal = 0
    listMean = mean(someList)
    for a in someList:
        newNum = (float(a) - listMean)**2
        newList.append(newNum)

    for z in newList:
        sdTotal += float(z)

    standardDeviation = sdTotal/(len(newList))

    return standardDeviation
```

Comment: can you add mean,standDev functions

Comment: Added in the edit the functions for those. They both seem to be working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pearson Correlation Coefficient

[image: Pearson Correlation Coeficient]

## Code (modified)

```
def mean(someList):
    total = 0
    for a in someList:
        total += float(a)
    mean = total/len(someList)
    return mean
def standDev(someList):
    listMean = mean(someList)
    dev = 0.0
    for i in range(len(someList)):
        dev += (someList[i]-listMean)**2
    dev = dev**(1/2.0)
    return dev
def correlCo(someList1, someList2):

    # First establish the means and standard deviations for both lists.
    xMean = mean(someList1)
    yMean = mean(someList2)
    xStandDev = standDev(someList1)
    yStandDev = standDev(someList2)
    # r numerator
    rNum = 0.0
    for i in range(len(someList1)):
        rNum += (someList1[i]-xMean)*(someList2[i]-yMean)

    # r denominator
    rDen = xStandDev * yStandDev

    r =  rNum/rDen
    return r

print(correlCo([1,2,3,4,4,8], [3,3,4,5,8,9]))
```

## Output

```
0.884782972876
```

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: This works! Thank you. I have a question about the finding of  r numerator part. Is this taking the sum of each product from the same position (position of i) in each list? Wouldn't this be an issue since the list contains strings and not floats/ints? Why is it that it does not need mapped out first?

Comment: @DeathPox You are misguided, Lists has numbers not strings.

Comment: if you supply like this ['1','2','3','4','4','8'], ['3','3','4','5','8','9'] then it is strings. But we send it as [1,2,3,4,4,8], [3,3,4,5,8,9]

Comment: ah! I forgot that I used numbers in the example. I actually am getting my lists from a data sheet that keeps them as strings. so all I need to do is apply the map function to convert it all to floats.

Answer (score 4):

The Pearson correlation can be calculated with numpy's [`corrcoef`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html).

```
import numpy
numpy.corrcoef(list1, list2)[0, 1]
```

Comment: As I've stated, it's important that this is done with the default library, and not to import anything like numpy or pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Your standard deviation is wrong. You forgot to take the squareroot.
You are actually returning variance and not standard deviation from that function.
@DeathPox

Comment: @DeathPox also, you are using population standard deviation, where as you should use sample standard deviation i.e 
standardDeviation = square-root ( sdTotal / (len(newList) -1) )

https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/standard-deviation.php

Answer (score 0):

Normally according to the standard deviation formula, you should have divided the dev to the sample number (length of the list) before sqrrt it.Right?
I mean:
dev += ((someList[i]-listMean)**2)/len(someList)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl6ib.jpg)